# One-hot (dummy) encoding of categorical data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

How to convert categorical data to one-hot encoded numeric format. Output format is depicted in the figure below:
[image]

Is it possible to automatically extract data classes and create columns for each class without having to create all columns (White, Red, Black, ...) manually in Excel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could do it with formulas

from your image above you could write in cell  E2

```
 =INDEX($B:$B,COLUMN(H:H)-COLUMN($E:$E))    'DRAG FORMULA ACROSS AS NEEDED
```

in cell D3 use

```
=A3                                         'DRAG FORMULA DOWN AS NEEDED
```

and in cell E3 use

```
=IF($B3=E$2,1,0)                   'DRAG FORMULA ACROSS AND DOWN AS NEEDED
```